# How to define the css :focus state in a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a resizable textarea:

```js
var KeyDown;
$(".TxtArea > div").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("Resize");
    $("body").addClass("UnSelectable");
    KeyDown = 1;
    $("textarea").css("opacity","0.3");
  $("textarea").focus(function() { $(this).css("border-color","#ccc") });
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $(".TxtArea").removeClass("Resize");
    $("body").removeClass("UnSelectable");
    KeyDown = 0;
    $("textarea").css("opacity","1");
    $("textarea").focus(function() { $(this).css("border-color","#07c") });
});
$(document).mousemove(function(Event){
    if (KeyDown == 1 && $(".TxtArea").hasClass("Resize")) {
        var Height = Event.pageY - $(".TxtArea").children("textarea").offset().top;
        $("textarea").height(Height);
    }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline:none;
}

textarea:focus{
  border: 1px solid #07c;
}


.TxtArea {
    width: 300px;
}

.TxtArea > textarea {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    resize: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.TxtArea > div {
    height: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
}
.TxtArea > div:hover {
    cursor: n-resize;
}

.UnSelectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="TxtArea">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div>.....</div>
</div>
```

Please follow these steps:

- run the above fiddle
- write something on that textarea
- click on x-scroll bar on the bottom of textarea and keep it
- move your mouse and resize that textarea (Now border color is `#ccc` and opacity is `0.3`)
- after resizing, leave your finger from click (Now opacity will be `1` but border doesn't change)

Why border doesn't change? and how can I return it to `#07c` after unclicking. How can I do that? (I want something exactly like SO)

---

**Note:** I want to set `#07c` just only `focus` state of that textarea after unclicking (Not a permanent border)

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me.  Have you tested in multiple browsers?  EDIT: So this is really interesting, the div actually rendered at #ccc even though the border-color for the element was that blue.  Not sure what's going on, but might have something to do with browser defaults?

Comment: @RobertIngrum Do you know what I want exactly?

Comment: Why are you setting the focus event in the mouse down event?  Use a focus event handler and a blur event handler to turn it on and off.

Comment: @Bindrid: I think he's trying to set the border color.  Probably would have been easier to just add a toggleable class...

Comment: @RobertIngrum emm I think toggle class could be a good idea ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure exactly why your focus code wasn't working, but in general, this is just better practice.  Typically you want the css to handle all of the styling and the javascript just toggles it.  It just keeps things cleaner and more organized.

So you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/psp12a0n/

The main thing that was changed was this part in the javascript:

```
$(".TxtArea > div").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("Resize");
    $("body").addClass("UnSelectable");
    KeyDown = 1;
    $("textarea").addClass('inactive');
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $(".TxtArea").removeClass("Resize");
    $("body").removeClass("UnSelectable");
    KeyDown = 0;
    $("textarea").removeClass('inactive');
});
```

And this in the css:

```
textarea:focus,
textarea:active {
    border: 1px solid #07c;
}

textarea.inactive {
    opacity: .3;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Just what is this in the css codes? `textarea:active`

Comment: You might not need it, but it's just saying that if the textarea is active (or currently being clicked) enable that styling.